# Update a datetime with conversion from a string date

Tags: mysql, datetime

I want to update a date field from another table's field with something like this :

```
UPDATE  table1
left join table2 on table1.key = table2.key
set table1.old_date = STR_TO_DATE(table2.string_date,'%Y%m%d %T');

SELECT table1.old_date, table2.string_date, STR_TO_DATE(string_date,'%Y%m%d')) as "new_dob"
left join table2 on table1.key = table2.key
```

my old_date is a datetime field, and my string_date is a string date with format 'YYYYMMDD'
When I do my select my dates are well formatted, but when I try to update it is failing with error :

```
Data Truncation error occurred on a write  of column 0Data was 0 bytes long and 0 bytes were transferred.
```

I think it is a date format problem, but I can't find a real solution ( i tried several) based on this error on community here.

Thanks

Edit : 
I add here some informations about my db :

```
ColumnIndex getColumnName   getColumnTypeName   getPrecision    getScale    isNullable  getTableName    getSchemaName   getCatalogName  getColumnClassName  getColumnDisplaySize    getColumnLabel  getColumnType   isAutoIncrement isCaseSensitive isCurrency  isDefinitelyWritable    isReadOnly  isSearchable    isSigned    isWritable
1   string_date VARCHAR 8   0   1   dump_external_customer      my_db   java.lang.String    8   string_date 12  false   false   false   true    false   true    false   true
2   old_date    DATETIME    19  0   0   customer        my_db   java.sql.Timestamp  19  old_date    93  false   false   false   true    false   true    false   true
```

19750921

1970-08-17 00:00:00

my converted date
1975-09-21

Comment: Are you using Squirrel with the Oracle Connection/J driver? I am and I got that same "Data Truncation error occurred on a write  of column 0Data was 0 bytes long and 0 bytes were transferred." which led me to your question. It's not a very helpful error message.

Answer (score 0):

If the format is "YYYYMMDD" then there is no time component.  So don't look for it in `str_to_date()`:

```
UPDATE table1 left join
       table2
     on table1.key = table2.key
    set table1.old_date = STR_TO_DATE(table2.string_date, '%Y%m%d');
```

Of course, MySQL does recognize that format as a date, so you can also just use `date()`:

```
UPDATE table1 left join
       table2
     on table1.key = table2.key
    set table1.old_date = DATE(table2.string_date);
```

Comment: I tried with date instead of str_to_date, it is still working well in select but same error on update. Maybe it is due to the fact that I have a "datetime" old_date and not a "date"?

Comment: Assigning `date` values to `datetime` is fine.  The issue is more likely that some value somewhere in the table does not match the date format.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE  table1
left join table2 on table1.key = table2.key
set table1.old_date = date_format(STR_TO_DATE(table2.string_date,'%Y%m%d'),'%Y-%m-%d');

Comment: Your dob values are incorrect. MySQL's date format is yyyy-mm-dd. Most likely you're getting the default 0000-00-00 stored and the data truncation error from that.

Comment: the dob is well displayed and the content isnt default value 0000-00-00 but the date I expect to update like 1956-05-25, my problem is on the update not the select

Comment: please share some records from old.date and string_date to see the date format

Comment: I just edited my post with structure and data. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Squirrel using the Oracle MySQL Connector/J driver,

This works:

```
select date('2016-01-11 06:40:10.188918 UTC') as bbb;
```

But this fails:

```
drop table if exists temp_junk;

create temporary table temp_junk as
select date('2016-01-11 06:40:10.188918 UTC') as bbb;
```

with the Error:

```
Data Truncation error occurred on a write  of column 0Data was 0 bytes long and 0 bytes were transferred.
Error occurred in:
create temporary table temp_junk as
    select date('2016-01-11 06:40:10.188918 UTC') as bbb
```

In SQL fiddle ( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5025b3/1/0 ) I at least get a decent error message (but only with the CREATE statement, the simple SELECT still succeeds):

```
Data truncation: Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2016-01-11 06:40:10.188918 UTC'
```

Maybe your error is similar.